# Redux importing side effect returns Reducer Returned Undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following redux module:

```
import { Map, fromJS } from 'immutable'
import api from '../lib/api'
import config from '../config/application'
import storage from '../lib/storage'
import { history } from '../lib/create-store'

// Actions
const USER_LOGIN = 'ts/user/USER_LOGIN'
const USER_LOGIN_RESPONSE = 'ts/user/USER_LOGIN_RESPONSE'
const USER_LOGOUT = 'ts/user/USER_LOGOUT'
const CREATE_ACCOUNT_TEAM = 'ts/user/CREATE_ACCOUNT_TEAM'
const CREATE_ACCOUNT_TEAM_RESPONSE = 'ts/user/CREATE_ACCOUNT_TEAM_RESPONSE'
const RECEIVE_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'ts/user/RECEIVE_ACCESS_TOKEN'
const RECEIVE_USER = 'adsdean/user/RECEIVE_USER'

const initialState = Map({
  accessToken: null,
  loginPending: false,
  loginError: false,
  creatingAccountTeam: false,
  creatingAccountTeamSuccess: false,
  creatingAccountTeamError: Map({}),
  profile: Map({
    id: null,
    email: null,
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    company: null,
    mobile: null,
    mobileShare: true,
    dob: null
  })
})

// Reducer
export default function user (state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVE_ACCESS_TOKEN: {
      storage.save('key', action.token)
      api.setAuth(action.token)
      return state.set('accessToken', fromJS(action.token))
    }

    case USER_LOGIN:
      return state.set('loginPending', true)

    case USER_LOGIN_RESPONSE: {
      let nextState = state.set('loginPending', false)

      if (action.status === 'success') {
        nextState = nextState
          .set('loginError', initialState.loginError)
      } else {
        nextState = nextState.set('loginError', action.error)
      }

      return nextState
    }

    case USER_LOGOUT: {
      storage.delete('key')
      api.setAuth(null)
      return state.set('accessToken', null)
    }

    case CREATE_ACCOUNT_TEAM:
      return state.set('creatingAccountTeam', true)

    case CREATE_ACCOUNT_TEAM_RESPONSE: {
      console.log(action)

      let nextState = state.set('creatingAccountTeam', false)

      if (action.status === 'success')
        state.set('creatingAccountTeamSuccess', true)
      else
        nextState = nextState.set('creatingAccountTeamError', fromJS(action.error))

      return nextState
    }

    case RECEIVE_USER:
      return state
        .setIn('profile', 'id', action.payload.id)
        .setIn('profile', 'email', action.payload.email)
        .setIn('profile', 'firstName', action.payload.first_name)
        .setIn('profile', 'lastName', action.payload.last_name)
        .setIn('profile', 'company', action.payload.company)
        .setIn('profile', 'mobile', action.payload.mobile)
        .setIn('profile', 'mobileShare', action.payload.mobile_share)
        .setIn('profile', 'dob', action.payload.dob)
  }

  return state
}

// ==============================
// Action Creators
// ==============================

export const userLoginResponse = (status, error) => ({
  type: USER_LOGIN_RESPONSE,
  status,
  error,
})

export const receiveAccessToken = token => ({
  type: RECEIVE_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  token
})

export const userCreateWithTeamResponse = (status, error) => ({
  type: CREATE_ACCOUNT_TEAM_RESPONSE,
  status,
  error,
})

export const receiveUser = user => ({
  type: RECEIVE_USER,
  payload: user
})

export const getAccessToken = state =>
  state.get('accessToken')

export const isLoggedIn = state =>
  state.get('accessToken')


// ==============================
// SIDE EFFECTS
// ==============================
//
//

export const getUser = () => async dispatch => {

  api.request.get('/user')
    .then(response => {
      dispatch(receiveUser(response.data))
    })
    .catch(error => {
    })
}

export const userLogin = (username, password) => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN })

  api.request.post('/oauth/token', {
    username,
    password,
    'grant_type': 'password',
    'client_id': config.clientId,
    'client_secret': config.clientSecret,
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response)
    const { access_token } = response.data
    dispatch(userLoginResponse('success', null))
    dispatch(receiveAccessToken(access_token))
    dispatch(receiveUser(response.data))
    window.gtag('event', 'login')
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
    dispatch(userLoginResponse('error', error))
  })
}

export const userLogout = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: USER_LOGOUT })
  history.push('/')
  window.gtag('event', 'logout')
  //logFormSubmission('Logout')
}

export const userCreateWithTeam = (form) => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: CREATE_ACCOUNT_TEAM })

  api.request.post('/account/register/team', {
    email: form.email,
    password: form.password,
    'first_name': form.firstName,
    'last_name': form.lastName,
    company: form.company,
    name: form.name,
    location: form.location,
    dob: form.dob,
    mobile: form.mobile,
    'mobile_share': (form.mobileShare === true) ? 1 : 0
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response)
    dispatch(userCreateWithTeamResponse('success', null))
    dispatch(userLogin(form.email, form.password))
    window.gtag('event', 'create account and team')
    window.gtag('set', {'user_id': response.data.id})
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response)
    dispatch(userCreateWithTeamResponse('error', error.response.data))
  })
}
```

everything was working fine until I added the side effect function named `getUser`. As soon as I do `import { getUser } from '../../modules/user'` from one of my components/containers I get hit with

`Error: Reducer "user" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined.`

As soon as I comment out the import, everything else that uses the module continues working fine. What is it about that new side effect, that looks the same as the others that is causing this?

My create store code:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { ConnectedRouter, routerReducer, routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux'
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutablejs'
import { fromJS, Map } from 'immutable'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import user from '../modules/user'

const initialState = fromJS({})
const enhancers = []

const middleware = [
  thunk,
  routerMiddleware(history)
]

export const history = createHistory()

const reducer = combineReducers({
  user,
  router: routerReducer,
})

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const devToolsExtension = window.devToolsExtension

  if (typeof devToolsExtension === 'function') {
    enhancers.push(devToolsExtension())
  }
}

const composedEnhancers = compose(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  ...enhancers
)

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composedEnhancers
)

export default store
```

I can fix the error by moving initialState Map directly into the default param part of the reducer... It seems the error is produced when having it in a separate const. However it's been working that way for weeks before the introduction of this function...

e.g

```
// Reducer
export default function user (state = Map({
  accessToken: null,
  loginPending: false,
  loginError: false,
  creatingAccountTeam: false,
  creatingAccountTeamSuccess: false,
  creatingAccountTeamError: Map({}),
  profile: Map({
    id: null,
    email: null,
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null,
    company: null,
    mobile: null,
    mobileShare: true,
    dob: null
  })
}), action = {}) {
```

Answer (score 1):

setIn syntax that you have used is incorrect, the nested path needs to be inside `[]`.

```
    .setIn(['profile', 'id'], action.payload.id)
    .setIn(['profile', 'email'], action.payload.email)
    .setIn(['profile', 'firstName'], action.payload.first_name)
    .setIn(['profile', 'lastName'], action.payload.last_name)
    .setIn(['profile', 'company'], action.payload.company)
    .setIn(['profile', 'mobile'], action.payload.mobile)
    .setIn(['profile', 'mobileShare'], action.payload.mobile_share)
    .setIn(['profile', 'dob'], action.payload.dob)
```

Check this **[documentation](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/setIn)**

also in

```
if (action.status === 'success')
    state.set('creatingAccountTeamSuccess', true) .  // <--
```

you missed to assign this to `nextState`  which may lead to inconsistencies

Comment: Good spots thank you, it didn't fix the "Reducer "user" returned undefined during initialization." unfortunately though

Comment: Can you console.log() the result of state change in ' RECEIVE_USER` case statement, also try and remove async in  `export const getUser = () => async dispatch => {`, since its not doing anything there

Comment: also please confirm if you get the user data in getUser function call before dispatching

Comment: The error is on immediate page load so there is no ajax calls etc called to check the return of

Comment: I've added my create store function in the original question if it helps

Comment: as you said, just importing getUser causes a problem, or is it that you are using it somewhere. also I think the problem could be the initialState passed with createStore as well, can you try `const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  composedEnhancers
)`

Comment: I'm not using getUser anywhere yet, just importing the function into a component which causes the immediate error. I've tried removing initial state as you suggest from `createStore` but no joy I'm afraid

Comment: I can fix the error by moving initialState Map directly into the default param part of the reducer... It seems the error is produced when having it in a separate const. However it's been working that way for weeks before the introduction of this function...